# application of Change of basis of linear mapping matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Define $D:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ by $D(p)(x)=p'(x)$. Find the matrix D with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{1,1+x,1+x+x^2\}$ of $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I've done something wrong in my working here and I cant figure out what. Also im not sure whether I used the notations correctly.

Also I know that it can be found without the using the formula, but I want to know specifically why I was wrong.

**Here's my attempt:**

$D$ in standard basis is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\0&0&2\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

change of basis matrix $C_{\mathcal{B}}^{SB}$ from standard to $\mathcal{B}$ is the same as all the standard basis put in $\mathcal{B}$'s form:
$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&1&-1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

By formula : $D_{\mathcal{B}}$ = $C_{\mathcal{B}}^{SB}DC_{\mathcal{B}}^{SB-1}$ =
$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&2\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

I know that $D_{\mathcal{B}}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&-1\\0&0&2\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, but where did i do wrong?

Comment: $D(e_3)=D(1+x+x^2)=1+2x=2(1+x)-1=2e_2-e_1$. So the third column of matrix $D$ is wrong.

Comment: @Chrystomath What you are describing is $D_{\mathcal{B}}$ I know you can find $D_{\mathcal{B}}$ that way, but I want to ensure I have a correct understanding of the change of basis formula. Where in this case, I got a wrong answer.

Comment: In the standard basis, $D(e_3)=D(x^2)=2x=2e_2$, so the third column is also wrong.

Comment: @Chrystomath cheers thank you